# Is replacing conditional logic with CASE statements efficient in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure that does something like:

```
IF @Param = '1'
    SELECT HT.HeaderKey, HT.Description,
           (SELECT SUM(E1) -- E1 is actually a complex expression
            FROM   DetailTable DT INNER JOIN ...
                                  INNER JOIN ...
                                  INNER JOIN ...
            WHERE  DT.HeaderKey = HT.HeaderKey)
    FROM   HeaderTable HT
ELSE IF @Param = '2'
    SELECT HT.HeaderKey, HT.Description,
           (SELECT SUM(E2) -- E2 is yet another complex expression
            FROM   DetailTable DT INNER JOIN ... -- Here, DetailTable is not
                                  INNER JOIN ... -- joined to the same tables
                                  INNER JOIN ... -- as in the first case
            WHERE  DT.HeaderKey = HT.HeaderKey)
    FROM   HeaderTable HT
-- Etc. There are five cases.
```

I *would like* to reduce the query to the following:

```
SELECT HT.HeaderKey, HT.Description,
       CASE @Param
         WHEN '1'
           (SELECT SUM(E1)
            FROM   DetailTable DT INNER JOIN ...
                                  INNER JOIN ...
                                  INNER JOIN ...
            WHERE  DT.HeaderKey = HT.HeaderKey)
         WHEN '2'
           (SELECT SUM(E2)
            FROM   DetailTable DT INNER JOIN ...
                                  INNER JOIN ...
                                  INNER JOIN ...
            WHERE  DT.HeaderKey = HT.HeaderKey)
         -- Etc.
         ELSE 0
       END
FROM   HeaderTable HT
```

However, if SQL Server evaluates *all* the cases, regardless of which one will be actually returned, the modified query would be grossly inefficient.

Thus, I'd like to know, does SQL Server evaluate *all* the cases in a `CASE` statement, or only the first one that satisfies the `CASE`'s condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server's CASE statement, as mentioned in [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71950/), does take advantage of short-circuiting so in the example shown it will not evaluate the results of every possible CASE outcome for every row.
However, you will still get a less efficient query than your current format as you'll then be forcing all outcomes to share the same execution plan, which may not be optimal. Depending on the differences between the CASE subqueries the effect could be quite significant.

Comment: How is his current format forcing each query to share the same plan? The current format has separate queries. Each one has some difference somewhere, if they don't then why the case?

Comment: It will just add a different path in the plan for each `case` outcome. There's no particular reason for thinking that additional path will cause other parts of the plan to be worse.

Comment: You're reading my answer wrong - it says "will still get a less efficient query THAN your CURRENT format". The OP's second part is their proposed format, which is less efficient than their current format (although probably a bit easier to maintain).

Comment: I've amended it slightly to remove an unintended ambiguity in that sentence.

Comment: I believe you're correct that I was misreading... but even the amended version has issues. As Martin points outs the optimizer can shortcut the case. There will be ONE plan for the entire query but each Case will generate its own optimal path. But if you're saying that it's possible that for one Case, you might want to Start with the header table before evaluation of that path, then yes, I agree and that's a very subtle understand and explanation of the optimizer. +1

Answer (score 2):

No it adds a "passthru predicate" to the plan which ensures that it only evaluates the queries necessary. See [Subqueries in CASE Expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the joins are the same in each subquery, i'd try something like this:

```
;with dt as
(
    select
        HeaderKey,
        sum(case @Param
            when 1 then E1
            when 2 then E2
            ...) as ExpressionSum
    from DetailTable DT
        inner join...
    group by dt.HeaderKey
)
select
    ht.HeaderKey,
    ht.description,
    dt.ExpressionSum
from HeaderTable HT
    inner join dt
        on HT.HeaderKey=dt.HeaderKey
```

or i could be grossly misunderstanding what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: "Here, DetailTable is not joined to the same tables as in the first case."  NOTICE the comment. It's not the same tables...

Answer (score -1):

You will almost always get a faster result with a set based solution vs. a procedural based solution in SQL Server (and all RDMS's).

Comment: It is set based. He's asking which "set" will be faster.

Comment: If statements aren't set based in SQL Server.

Comment: Right, but after the IF, there will be a SQL Statement executed. The "work" is being done in a SET... the evaluation of an IF is less than minuscule in comparison to the sql. You're taking a simple maxim to an extreme. We say set based is better, doesn't mean that the very first line of code kills performance. It means don't loop and process tables row by row.

Comment: Not really. For all we know he needs to run that every few seconds.